# How to get the counts of a particular pattern in a file?

Tags: python, regex

I have a file, which has the below format. I'm trying to find how many number of such format exists.

**Complete Format : When i say complete format, it should start with the line PATTERN 123456789.000 10.10.10.10 1 10 0 - followed by any text and ends by PATTERN 9876543210.000 1.1.1.1 1 10 9 any_string2**

Scenario1: "2 complete Formats"

```
PATTERN 123456789.000 10.10.10.10 1 10 0 -    #Data-set1 starts
can be anything here of any number of lines
and not concerned 
PATTERN 123456789.000 10.10.10.10 1 10 9 any_string1   ##Data-set1 ends
PATTERN 9876543210.000 1.1.1.1 1 10 0 -         #Data-set2 starts
can be anything here of any number of lines
and not concerned 
PATTERN 9876543210.000 1.1.1.1 1 10 9 any_string2     #Data-set2 ends
```

Scenario2: 1 Complete format and 1 error/incorrect format

```
PATTERN 123456789.000 10.10.10.10 1 10 0 -    #Data-set1 starts
can be anything here of any number of lines
and not concerned 
PATTERN 123456789.000 10.10.10.10 1 10 9 any_string1   ##Data-set1 ends
#Missing that begin line PATTERN for Data-set2
can be anything here of any number of lines
and not concerned 
PATTERN 9876543210.000 1.1.1.1 1 10 9 any_string2     #Data-set2 ends
```

Scenario3: None of the format created successfully

```
PATTERN 123456789.000 10.10.10.10 1 10 0 -    #Data-set1 starts
can be anything here of any number of lines
and not concerned 
#Missing end PATTERN line for Data-set1
#Missing that begin line PATTERN for Data-set2
can be anything here of any number of lines
and not concerned 
PATTERN 9876543210.000 1.1.1.1 1 10 9 any_string2     #Data-set2 ends
```

Tried this regex, but it works only one data-set is present in a file.

```
PATTERN\s+\d+.\d+\s+\d+.\d+.\d+.\d+\s+\d+\s+\d+\s+\d+\s+-(.*)PATTERN\s+\d+.\d+\s+\d+.\d+.\d+.\d+\s+\d+\s+\d+\s+\d+\s+.*
```

Scenario1: "2 complete Formats"
Scenario2: 1 Complete format and 1 error/incorrect format
Scenario3: None of the format created successfully

**Code Generated from regex101.com**

```
import re

regex = r"PATTERN\s+\d+.\d+\s+\d+.\d+.\d+.\d+\s+\d+\s+\d+\s+\d+\s+-(.*)PATTERN\s+\d+.\d+\s+\d+.\d+.\d+.\d+\s+\d+\s+\d+\s+\d+\s+.*"

test_str = ("PATTERN 123456789.000 10.10.10.10 1 10 0 -    \n"
    "a-12345 any random stuffs here\n"
    "c-34444 again any randomstuffs here\n"
    "PATTERN 123456789.000 10.10.10.10 1 10 9 any_string1      ")

matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL)

for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches, start=1):

    print ("Match {matchNum} was found at {start}-{end}: {match}".format(matchNum = matchNum, start = match.start(), end = match.end(), match = match.group()))

    for groupNum in range(0, len(match.groups())):
        groupNum = groupNum + 1

        print ("Group {groupNum} found at {start}-{end}: {group}".format(groupNum = groupNum, start = match.start(groupNum), end = match.end(groupNum), group = match.group(groupNum)))
```

Comment: Show how you're using the regexp in the Python script.

Comment: You have to mask the `.` like `\.`. It will match like this as well, but it will match with ANY character, not just with the dot!

Comment: I tried that pattern which only matches one format. Above pasted the code generated from regex101.com

Comment: You can't use a regexp to search for things that *don't* match the pattern, unless you can define an alternate pattern that matches the errors.

Comment: Check out this gist mate. It is not regex solution, but it is what you need (refactoring needed of course): https://gist.github.com/greedyf00x/171c91b3a32fb5278f0e5f2f49d67377

Comment: I thought i can optimize it by using regex in this fashion. So, can't it be achieved ?